# How do I make the bottom to be exactly the same as in figma file

Tags: html, css

[image]

This is how it should look like

[image]

This is how it looks

```
<div class="button-section-two"> 
            <div class="button-icon-two">
            
            <object data="/assets/icons/Vector (1).svg" class="icon-two"> </object>
            </div>
            <span class="button-two-text">Start listening</span>
          </div>
          </div>

.button-section-two {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 16px 24px;
  gap: 8px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 165px;
  height: 48px;
  left: 24px;
  top: 342px;
  background: #65d46e;
  border-radius: 200px;
}

.button-two-text {
  width: 97px;
  height: 16px;
  font-family: "Lato";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 100%;
  /* identical to box height, or 16px */
  letter-spacing: -0.01em;
  color: #000000;
  /* Inside auto layout */
  flex: none;
  order: 1;
  flex-grow: 0;
}

.button-icon-two {
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  /* Inside auto layout */
  flex: none;
  order: 0;
  flex-grow: 0;
}
```

How do I make the button to look the same as in the first image? Tried to use the same css code from figma but didnt work eaither. Seems like font is a little bit too big but I think I should suposed to used the same as in figma, right?

Comment: Please edit your question to include a runnable StackSnippet that functions as a [mcve]

Answer (score -1):

Try to adjust the width of

```
.button-two-text
```

(increase/decrease)